# 2. 3 PERFORMANCE: ACCURATE METADATA

Tags: android, ios, app-store-connect, metadata, apprtcdemo

I don't understand this itunesconnect message?

I use this library:

https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios/issues

> We noticed that your app or its metadata includes irrelevant
>   third-party platform information. Specifically, Android is mentioned
>   in the App Description.
>
> Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its metadata is not
>   permitted on the App Store unless there is specific interactive
>   functionality.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please remove all instances of this information from your app and its
>   metadata, including the app description, What's new info, previews,
>   and screenshots.
>
> Since your iTunes Connect Application State is Rejected, a new binary
>   will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload
>   the new binary.
>
> NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all App
>   Localizations by selecting each specific localization and making
>   appropriate changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to use Android tm in your application captions or description.